# PHP - dollarsign in file path

Tags: php, glob, network-share

How to access files with a $-sign in a network share?

```
\\server\data$\fileshere
```

Tried escaping the backslashes, but my guess is that it's the dollarsign that creates problems?

EDIT:

Okay - here goes. On the server there is this file :

```
\\server\data$\filetest.txt';
```

If I want to check for a wildcard match like 'file*' my code looks this this :

```
$filecheck = '\\server\data$\file*';
## (also tried escaping \ : $filecheck = '\\\\server\\data$\\file*';
$check = glob($filecheck);
```

It does not match.

Comment: How are you trying to access it? Could you add your code?

Comment: Any votes for the backslash being used as an escape character? Vote with an UV on this comment

Comment: You're welcome Martin and thanks for that. Let's all delete our comments here. I'll @ da gents to do the same so we can clear the comments area.

Comment: @andrewsi we can clear the comments now. OP has posted code. Edit: mine are deleted.

Comment: @Martin If you want to check for all files, I think you're going about it the wrong way. Your Network share syntax seems ok, but it could be the way you're using the `glob()` function here. Have you gone through the manual? http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php

Comment: oh...oh..oh... you're trying to use a variable inside single quotes; that won't get parsed. It needs to be double quotes `$filecheck = "\\server\data$\file*";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- No he is not. `$` is part of filename

Comment: @Fred-ii- It works quite fine on a local directory - but just not using this network share; I thought it was the $-sign in the file path that created the problems. I'll try a different approach. thanks

Comment: @RiggsFolly ah ok. Martin... any errors/warnings/notices? If your system's not already setup to catch/display, see if error reporting shows http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and might have something to do with admin rights also.

Comment: I'll give it a shot; And excuse me for not replying in a while - I'm about to land, and they are shutting down the wifi ;-)

Comment: @Martin Happy landings, *cheers*

Comment: may i suggest, on windows, you always use '/' (forward slash),  in file paths rather than '\' (back slash), which needs to be escaped in PHP strings. Windows is quite happy with this. Even in network shares. If using the CLI just put it in quotes.

Comment: As it turned out the only way I could get it working was by using 4 x \ in the beginning - and then single \ for the rest.
Thanks for all your comments / suggestions!!

Comment: Hey Martin (I see you landed safely-wink). Strangely enough, @RiggsFolly had an answer lined about that actually. Wondering if he's going to undelete it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- - thanks - got down safely :-)
RiggsFolly answer was what I already tried (\\\\ - and then \\ on the rest). But very close indeed :-)

Comment: @Martin *Ah, benissimo!!* Actually, he and I were chatting this over earlier, and had something else lined up for it, which I believe was what you said was the clincher. He was testing it on his end.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Well I undeleted my answer with my finding. I have had issues with this before and found that a number of different solutions work

Comment: @RiggsFolly *benissimo!* grazie mille.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not added enough backslashes for the UNC part, also its safest to escape the escape char so always use `\\` for one backslash.

Use

```
$filecheck = '\\\\server\data$\file*';
```

It also works for me using

```
$filecheck = '\\\\servers\\data$\\file*';
```